# Is there any way to manually insert content into the response cache in OkHttp?

Tags: okhttp

My application is currently downloading aggregated content in a single response, however sometimes it needs to also fetch elements of that response by their individual uris.

I would like to be able to save each of these elements from the aggregated response into the cache under its individual uri so that when it is requested the app doesn't need to go to the network for it.

Is there any way to achieve this with OkHttp?

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work.

```java
        String json = encoder.writeValueAsString(object);
        Request newRequest = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
        ResponseBody body = ResponseBody
                .create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), json);
        Response resp = new Response.Builder().body(body)
                .request(newRequest).code(200).protocol(HTTP_1_1)
                .header("content-type", "application/json")
                .message("OK").body(body)
                .networkResponse(new Response.Builder().code(200)
                        .request(newRequest).protocol(HTTP_1_1)
                        .header("content-type", "application/json")
                        .message("OK").build())
                .build();
        Sink cacheSink = getOk().cache().put$okhttp(resp).body();
        cacheSink.write(resp.body().source().getBuffer(),
                json.getBytes().length);
        cacheSink.close();
```

See [Is manually inserting data into okhttp cache safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987491/is-manually-inserting-data-into-okhttp-cache-safe)